# Python API call not writing to file

Tags: python, xml, api, twinfield

In the past, I used the Power Query Editor in `PowerBI` to request a `sessionID` and then use that query to query an API. However, this dependency does not work with PowerBI Service.

So now I'm trying to do the API call externally via Python.

I can get it to work using the following code

```py
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from zeep import Client
import query
import authentication

# implement logging to logfile:

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logging.getLogger('zeep').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger('urllib3').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
handler = logging.FileHandler('./twinfield.log')
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#setup connection to Twinfields, provide credentials and receive cluster:

sessionlogin = r'https://login.twinfield.com/webservices/session.asmx?wsdl'
login = Client(sessionlogin)

auth = login.service.Logon(authentication.username, authentication.password, authentication.organisation)

auth_header = auth['header']['Header']
cluster = auth['body']['cluster']

#Use cluster to create a session:

url_session = cluster + r'/webservices/session.asmx?wsdl'
session = Client(url_session)

#Select a company for the session:

session.service.SelectCompany('NL001', _soapheaders={'Header': auth_header})

#And then connect to the actual webservice:

proces_url = cluster + r'/webservices/processxml.asmx?wsdl'
proces = Client(proces_url)

#Send the query and get the twinfield server response (XML):

response = proces.service.ProcessXmlString(query.XML_String,  _soapheaders={'Header': auth_header})

logger.debug('response received of %s characters', len(response))

#Write raw response to XML:

xmlfilename = 'twinfield.xml'

f = open(xmlfilename, 'w')
f.write(response)
f.close()

logger.debug('Raw XML file written: %s', xmlfilename)
```

Query.py looks like this:

```py
XML_String= r'''<columns code='030_1'>
<column>
    <field>fin.trs.head.office</field>
    <label>Administratie</label>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <ask>false</ask>
    <operator>none</operator>
    <from></from>
</column>
<column>
    <field>fin.trs.head.year</field>
    <label>Jaar</label>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <ask>true</ask>
    <operator>none</operator>
    <from>2020</from>
</column>
<column>
    <field>fin.trs.head.period</field>
    <label>Periode</label>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <ask>true</ask>
    <operator>none</operator>
</column>
<column>
    <field>fin.trs.head.date</field>
    <label>Boekdatum</label>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <ask>false</ask>
    <operator>none</operator>
    <from></from>
    <to></to>
    <finderparam></finderparam>
</column>
<column>
    <field>fin.trs.line.dim1</field>
    <label>Grootboekrek.</label>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <ask>true</ask>
    <operator>between</operator>
    <from></from>
    <to></to>
    <finderparam></finderparam>
</column>
<column>
    <field>fin.trs.line.dim1name</field>
    <label>Grootboekrek.naam</label>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <ask>false</ask>
    <operator>none</operator>
    <from></from>
    <to></to>
    <finderparam></finderparam>
</column>
</columns>'''
```

The code writes fine to XML file. However, when I start adding more columns and run the code, instead of a black py.exe suddenly there is an onslaught of text running through the screen. When it finishes, no-log or XML file is written.

This is what I mean:

[image: 1]

Comment: For anyone having the same trouble, i fixed it by setting HugeTree = True in the parser object settings. lxml sets it to False automatically, so any xml file over 10mb won't work

Comment: We made a complete python module for querying Twinfield. See [homepage](https://pypi.org/project/twinfield/) here and to install: `pip install twinfield`